# Prove that $ \text{len}(q^*) \le 3\text{len}(q) -2 $

Tags: logic, induction, propositional-calculus

Prove by induction where q is a formula in proposition logic:

$$ \text{len}(q^*) \le 3\text{len}(q) -2 $$

Where the star property (*) is defined as follows:

$$ \text{atom}^* = \text{atom} $$
 $$ (\neg(q))^*=  \neg(q^*) $$
 $$ (w \land x)^* = \neg (\neg w^* \lor \neg x^*) $$

The function Len gives the total number of connectives + the number of proposition letters in a formula.

My proof up till now, here for atoms:

$$ \text{len}(q^*) \le 3\text{len}(q) - 2 $$
$$ \text{len}(q)  \le 3\text{len}(q) - 2$$
$$ 1 \le 1 $$

And here for conjunction:

$$ \text{len}((q \land w)^*) \le 3\text{len}(q \land w) - 2 $$
$$ \text{len}( \neg(\neg w^* \lor \neg x^*)) \le 3(\text{len}(q) + \text{len}(w) + 1) -2 $$
$$ \text{len}(w^*) + len (q^*) + 4 \le 3(\text{len}(q) + \text{len}(w) + 1) -2 $$

Is this correct or sufficient? Any recommendations? I have no idea how to solve the last inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments, a self contained proof would have been better than just finishing what Ferengi Godfried started and pointing out that the last part can be done in the same way. So here is a full, self-contained proof.

**Answer:** We have to prove by induction that for a formula $q$ in propositional logic which consists only of atoms, negation and conjunction (since the $^*$-operator is only defined for atoms, $\wedge$ and $\neg$), the following inequality holds:

\begin{equation}
\text{len}(q^*) \leq 3\text{len}(q) - 2\qquad (1)
\end{equation}

The induction is on $\text{len}$ of the formula $q$ (i.e. on the number of connectives $\wedge$ and $\neg$ plus the number of atoms in $q$) and has three steps, the base case (where $q$ is an atom) and then two induction steps for negation and conjunction.

**Atoms:** According to the definition of the $^*$-operator, we have $q^* = q$ for every atom $q$. Using $\text{len}(q) = 1$ for atoms, the inequality follows straightforward:

\begin{equation}
\text{len}(q^*) = \text{len}(q) = 1 \leq 1 = 3\text{len}(q) - 2
\end{equation}

**Negation:** For negation, we have $(\neg q)^* = \neg(q^*)$ for a formula $q$. Noting that

\begin{equation}
3\text{len}(\neg q) - 2 = 3(\text{len}(q) + 1) - 2 = 3\text{len}(q) + 1 \qquad (2)
\end{equation}

we have

\begin{equation}
\text{len}((\neg q)^*) = \text{len}(\neg(q^*)) = \text{len}(q^*) + 1 \leq 3\text{len}(q) - 2 + 1 \leq 3\text{len}(\neg q) - 2 
\end{equation}

The induction hypothesis $(1)$ was used at the first inequality and $(2)$ at the second.

**Conjunction:** Again by definition, we have $(w \wedge x)^* = \neg(\neg w^* \vee \neg x^*)$ for formulas $w$ and $x$. Since

\begin{equation}
3\text{len}(w \wedge x) - 2 = 3(\text{len}(w) + \text{len}(x) + 1) - 2 = 3\text{len}(w) + 3\text{len}(x) + 1 \qquad (3)
\end{equation}

and

\begin{equation}
\text{len}((w \wedge x)^*) = \text{len}(\neg(\neg w^* \vee \neg x^*)) = \text{len}(w^*) + \text{len}(x^*) + 4 \qquad (4)
\end{equation}

we have

\begin{equation}
\text{len}((w \wedge x)^*) = \text{len}(w^*) + \text{len}(x^*) + 4 \leq 3\text{len}(w) - 2 + 3\text{len}(x) - 2 + 4 \leq 3\text{len}(w \wedge x) - 2
\end{equation}

Again, $(4)$ was used at the first equality, the induction hypothesis $(1)$ at the first inequality, and $(3)$ at the second equality.

We have proven that the inequality holds for atoms, negation and conjunction, what means that we are finished.

Comment: -1 a complete, self contained proof woul be fine

Comment: @miracle173 Here you go. I couldn't understand why though, I have finished what Ferengi Godfried started for conjunction, and pointed out that the part that was left could be proved in the exact same way, a good exercise after providing the solution for conjunction. Overall, the answer got upvoted and accepted, so I guess it was ok for Ferengi Godfried, and I'm sure that he would have written a comment if he couldn't solve the last part.

Comment: Yes indeed it was already clear. Thanks for your help.

Comment: thank you for your edit. I turned the downvote to an upvote. I have the following questions: 1. I can't see why [functional completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_completeness) does matter in this proof? can you explain? 2. The proof is by induction on what?

Comment: @miracle173 Thank you for doing so. To your questions: 1. Functional completeness is the reason why it is sufficient to prove the inequality only for atoms, conjunction and negation. Since $\{\wedge, \neg\}$ is functional complete, every formula in propositional logic has an equivalent formula (in terms of truth values) that contains only $\wedge$ and $\neg$ as connectives. Equivalently, every connective in propositional logic can be defined using only $\wedge$ and $\neg$. So once we have shown that the inequality holds for atoms, $\wedge$ and $\neg$, we can conclude that it also holds for

Comment: arbitrary formulas $q$, we just have to replace the occuring connectives by their definition in terms of $\wedge$ and $\neg$. 2. The proof is by induction on "construction of formulas". There is a special name for it, but I'm not sure how it's called in english (I think it's "structural induction", in german it's called "Induktion nach Formelaufbau"). This makes sense because formulas are defined inductively in propositional logic, so it is sufficient to prove a statment for formulas (like an inequality) inductively according to the construction of formulas.

Comment: In fact, this type of induction is a common proof method in a lot of different logics, like propositional logic, first-order logic, modal logic etc.

Comment: @user331406: 1. functional completeness does not make sense here. It is a question about formulas (true or false or undefined) and not about true sentences of propositional logic. It also does not make sense to say you have shown it for arbitrary formulas because the * function is not defined for arbitrary formulas. And if one would define it for other operators, too, functional completeness would not help to show that the inequality is true for those other operators.

Comment: @user331406: 2. the induction can be on "len"  of the formula (= total number of connectives + the number of proposition letters). There is no need for mysterious terms. A formula is an atom (len =1) or the conjunction or negation of formulas with smaller len, for these the induction hypotheses is true.

Comment: @miracle173: 1. Yes, maybe you're right. One could assume though that the *-operator is also defined implicitly for the other connectives since it is defined for atoms, $\wedge$ and $\neg$. But I see that even if * is defined for all connectives, functional completeness doesn't work as argument since $\text{len}$ counts connectives and has nothing to do with truth values. I will change this, thanks for pointing it out.

Comment: @miracle173: 2. Well, I don't think that it really matters if we do the induction on $\text{len}$ of the formula or on "connectives" (i.e. structural induction), it ends in the same proof. I also don't think that this is a mysterious term, this term was used throughout all lectures I attended about logic, and it was used by assistans and professors as well (but maybe this isn't true for other unis, I don't know).

Comment: @user331406:  You are right, both are possible, "len" or "number of connectives". But you should choose one of them and incorporate it in your prove and not leave the reader unlear about this.

Comment: @miracle173: Yes that's a good point, I should have done this from the beginning in my proof. Thanks for the advice! I edited my answer, I hope that it is clear now.